# Delay without switching thread

Tags: rx-java2

Is possible delay execution with operator delay, but in same manner as works Thread.Sleep? It means without scheduling on different thread. A want to call delay on used io thread.

```
Single.just(new Object())
.delay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.subscribe().
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the `Scheduler` for the `delay` operator:

```
Single.just(new Object())
.delay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.io())
.subscribe()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to pass Schedulers.immediate() to the delay operator.